# How can I access JavaScript object in array?

Tags: javascript

My question is how can I Access the object in the array. As an example how can I access the property `country`?

```
var arr1 = [{country: "Schweiz", code: 'ch'},{country: "Deutschland", code: 'de'},{country: "Oesterreich", code: 'at'}]
```

Comment: which one do you like to get?

Comment: Maybe using `arr1[<some_index>].country` ?

Comment: You need to be more concise. Do you want to return a country based on a specific country name?

Comment: Array is a list of objects (countries in your case), so you need to decide which object you want to pick from this list. To get the first object you could use arr1[0] where 0 is an index. To pick an object based on a criteria (e.g. country code), you could use Array.find function

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax to acces an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/Object) [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/property/JavaScript) is:

```
array[index].objectProperty
```

So, with this said to access the country value of the first index you should use:

```
arr1[0].country  // Schweiz
```

So, for example, lets print out every country on your array:

```js
var arr1 = [{
    country: "Schweiz",
    code: 'ch'
  },
  {
    country: "Deutschland",
    code: 'de'
  },
  {
    country: "Oesterreich",
    code: 'at'
  }
];

arr1.forEach((item)=>{
  document.write(item.country+"<br>");
})
```

> ***Note:*** In the array structure you provided exists a syntax error. You are missing a comma, which is used to separate elements on your array.

Arrays are structures separated with commas, like this:

```
myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

So, to separate each index, you need to use a comma. You have:

```
var arr1 = [{
        country: "Schweiz",
        code: 'ch'
    }, // First separator comma
    {
        country: "Deutschland",
        code: 'de'
    } { // MISSING COMMA HERE
        country: "Oesterreich",
        code: 'at'
    }

]
```

So, just separate the new element with a comma:

```
var arr1 = [{
        country: "Schweiz",
        code: 'ch'
    },
    {
        country: "Deutschland",
        code: 'de'
    }, // ADDED COMMA
    {
        country: "Oesterreich",
        code: 'at'
    }

]
```

Hope this helps with your question. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index you just use the index

```
arr1[1].country;
```

If you want to look it up by country code you can find it

```js
var arr1 = [{country: "Schweiz", code: 'ch'},{country: "Deutschland", code: 'de'},{country: "Oesterreich", code: 'at'}];

const getCountry = (array, code) => array.find(country => country.code === code);

console.log(getCountry(arr1, 'de'));
```